# Has anyone ever seen a (ring oscillator) circuit like this?

Tags: oscillator, jitter

I first designed this using NT Multisim 14 and the simulation worked. Then I built it with breadboard but used **[NTE101](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/100to199/pdf/nte100.pdf)** Germanium transistors instead of [2N3904](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf) silicon transistors. When I tested it I noticed that when the input DC voltage is 10V++, it starts to oscillate continuously with no damping. I used only 1 capacitor placed in a T-bone connection between Q2 and Q3 so that there will be an imbalance in the ring upon startup to keep the oscillations going.

But the bigger question is: How do I reduce the jitter to a level so low that it will be inaudible? This is intended to be part of an audio frequency VCO(still need an amplifier and speaker to hear it).

I'd like some critique of this design; and if any of you have the components please test it and tell me whatcha got!

[image]

Comment: Jitter is phase noise: Random fluctuations in oscillator frequency.

Comment: If you want it to be stable, why not use an oscillator whose parameters are set by the values of passives like R and C, instead of the propagation of the transistors that is unknown and highly variable with temperature?

Comment: Yeah I don't get it. But if you put the cap in all 3 stages, you can make it 'chase' from one stage to the next in a controlled manner, but why bother having 3 stages when you can just have one transistor feeding back to itself?

Comment: Why using Ge transistors? They are a relic of the past. Are you just building the VCO for learning purposes or is it an actual design you want to deploy?

Comment: Ge is making a comeback because of its higher electron mobility and lower barrier potential. They also have a reputation for better sound(Ge transistor fuzz petals).

Comment: High mobility is needed for speed. Ge is used in high-speed device like [heterojunction transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction_bipolar_transistor) together with other materials, like Si and Ga, and the application fields are in the GHz range. For audio app it would be complete overkill. Moreover those NTE100/1 BJT are *SLOW* (see the rise time spec in the datasheet: ~200ns -- about ten times worse than the average Si low power BJT).

Comment: As for the Ge sounding "better" than Si it is a matter of taste, but this is something that relates on how amplification is done (so Ge BJT, like old vacuum tubes distort the signal in a different way and give out a different "sound"). You are building an oscillator, so it should produce a well-defined waveform. Anyway, if you are interested in audio, you may find the [Elliot Sound Products site](http://sound.whsites.net/articles.htm) interesting. Here is an article on [audiophiles myths](http://sound.whsites.net/articles/myths.html).

Comment: Lorenzo, it is true that the NTE101 transistors have a fairly long rise time. But I would not use them for digital/high frequency applications. This oscillator is intended to operate in the audio frequency range(20Hz to 20kHz) and this particular circuit seems to work pretty well.